# How to put give a name to s2ui submit button

Tags: grails, user-interface, spring-security

I am using the following code

> s2ui:submitButton elementId='reset' form='resetPasswordForm'
>   messageCode='spring.security.ui.resetPassword.submit(msg)'/>

which gives me Msg+ a button with no value.

I wan that the button should have the msg in its value.
I tried even giving the explicit value field but it does not regard it.

How do I edit the button's value then.
+

How to align the s2ui form.

the problem was in the taglib

> def submitButton = { attrs ->
>   String form =getRequiredAttribute(attrs, 'form', 'submitButton')
>   String elementId = getRequiredAttribute(attrs, 'elementId', 'submitButton')       > 
>   String text = resolveText(attrs)
>   def writer = getOut() 
>   //        writer << """
>   //        writer << ">${text}\n"
>   writer << "\n"
>   String javascript = """\$("#${elementId}").button();
>              \$('#${elementId}').bind('click', function() {
>                   document.forms.${form}.submit();});"""
>   writeDocumentReady writer, javascript
>   }

So this used to put the value as null and show the test as a link with a blank button

Comment: I got the problem was actually in the tag lib.. thanks...

Comment: But as I could not commit my local changes of plugin to server it did not help. So may be we should edit the plugin at server too where we host our application or create own own taglib instead of using the plugin's.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem was actually in the tag lib..

But as I could not commit my local changes of plugin to server it did not help. So may be we should edit the plugin at server too where we host our application or create own own taglib instead of using the plugin's.

So currently I am using my own submit button.